# My coords are NaN, NaN

Tags: javascript, nan, mouse-position

I am trying to get the coords of my mouse position on a canvas. but all i get back is NaN, NaN

```
var canvasBg = document.getElementById('canvasBg');
var ctxBg = canvasBg.getContext('2d');

var mouseX;
var mouseY;

canvasBg.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoved, false);
canvasBg.addEventListener('click', mouseClicked, false);

function mouseMoved(e) {

mouseX = e.pageX - canvasBg.pageOffsetLeft;
mouseY = e.pageY - canvasBg.pageOffsetTop;
document.getElementById('mouseCoors').innerHTML = 'X: ' + mouseX + ' Y: ' + mouseY;

}

function mouseClicked(e) {

    alert( mouseX + "," + mouseY);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way simpler:

```
function mouseMoved(e) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
    document.getElementById('mouseCoors').innerHTML = 'X: ' + mouseX + ' Y: ' + mouseY;
}

function mouseClicked(e) {
    alert( e.offsetX + "," + e.offsetY);
}
```

Comment: To answer why your original code doesn't work, pageOffsetLeft and pageOffsetTop don't exist. When you try to subtract undefined from a number, you get (appropriately) not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution!

Try this for your `mouseMoved` function:

```
function mouseMoved(e) {
    mouseX = e.x - canvasBg.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.y - canvasBg.offsetTop;

    document.getElementById('mouseCoors').innerHTML = 'X: ' + mouseX + ' Y: ' + mouseY;
}
```

Live preview of full code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpPvk/1/).

[Reference](http://miloq.blogspot.com/2011/05/coordinates-mouse-click-canvas.html)